# Solving radical Equation?

Tags: radicals

The question goes on about like this.

$$-2 = \sqrt{7 -2 b} - \sqrt{2 b + 3}$$

I tried squaring both sides but than that does not make sense as one side has 2 square roots. Then do I double it, like $(-2)^4$ 'cause there are two of them?

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$-2=\sqrt{7-2b}-\sqrt{2b+3}$$
Squaring both the sides, we get 
$$(-2)^2=(\sqrt{7-2b}-\sqrt{2b+3})^2$$
$$4=7-2b+2b+3-2\sqrt{7-2b}\sqrt{2b+3}$$
$$\sqrt{7-2b}\sqrt{2b+3}=3$$
Again, squaring both the sides, we get 
$$(7-2b)(2b+3)=3^2$$
$$b^2-2b-3=0$$$$\implies (b+1)(b-3)=0$$

I hope you can solve further

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering but how did you get  cause if you square the other side dont you cancel the square root, why is it there

Comment: As you see in the answer, we square twice the equation to eliminate square root. You can ask further if you have any query

Comment: Thanks again for answering but how did you get here sqrt(7-2b)(2b+3) = 3  what happened to 4=7-2b+2b-2sqrt(7-2b)(sqrt(2b+3)

Comment: you see that $2b$ term is cancelled out then we have $LHS=7-2b+2b+3-2\sqrt{7-2b}\sqrt{2b+3}=10-2\sqrt{7-2b}\sqrt{2b+3}=2(5-\sqrt{7-2b}\sqrt{2b+3}$   Now, divide by $2$ take $\sqrt{7-2b}\sqrt{2b+3}$ to the right side & constant term to the left finally, you find $$\sqrt{7-2b}\sqrt{2b+3}=3$$

Comment: Ohh did you move 2 and 5 to the other side? but how would you do that..to take it to the other side you would have to divide 2? i think i might be making this complex but would you be able to tell me how you got = 3 ??

Comment: Yeah, of course. You are absolutely correct. See when you take $2$ & $5$ to the other (right) side you get $5-2=3$

Comment: The solution $b=-1$ is a parasitc solution, due to squaring.

Comment: yes, you are correct, $b=3$ is acceptable value

Answer (score 0):

You eliminate the radicals by squaring, repeating the operation as many times as necessary. The simplest, in general is to isolate a radical in one side.

However, beware the equation obtained after squaring is implied by the original equation, but *not* equivalent to it. Indeed the main rule is:
$$A=\sqrt B\iff A^2=B\enspace \color{red}{\text{and}}\enspace A\ge 0$$
Here, we first observe the domain of *validity* of the equation is $\;\biggl[-\dfrac32,\dfrac72\biggr]$.

We can rewrite the equation as
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{7-2b}+2&=\sqrt{2b+3}\Rightarrow 7-2b+4+4\sqrt{7-2b}=2b+3\iff\sqrt{7-2b}=b-2\\&\iff 7-2b=b^2-4b+4\enspace \color{red}{\text{and}}\enspace b\ge 2\\
&\iff b^2-2b-3=(b+1)(b-3)=0\enspace \color{red}{\text{and}}\enspace b\ge 2
\end{align*}
Thus there is only one solution: $\;\color{red}{b=3}$.

You can check the solution to the final equation, $b=-1$, is not a solution to the initial equation, as the right-hand side is equal to $+2$ for this value of $b$.